# async/await jquery animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, async-await

I want to chain Jquery animations and for the sake of readability I'd like to keep my code "vertical" not "horizontal".

Here's what I've done but does not work:

```
async function close(id){
    return $(id).slideUp().promise();
}

async function shrink(id){
    return $(id).animate({width: '50%'}).promise();
}

[...]

function update(){
    await close("#myDiv");
    await shrink("#myDiv");
    doSomething();
}
```

But I get an error: `Syntax Error: await is only valid in async functions [...]`

I know I can chain Jquery animations (`foo().bar()`) or use these functions' callbacks but my question really is about `async/await`

Comment: `((async () => { /* your await code */ })())`

Comment: ...and you don't need async before `shrink` or `close`

Comment: Yeah ok got confused ; the async goes where the promise are awaited not where they are created

Comment: No - 2 sec @ted I write a answer

Comment: The reason you get a error is because a JS-file is not "async" at the top-level. 

This answer here provides a great description: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46515787/1514875

Comment: also let me update something

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use async/await at the top level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46515764/how-can-i-use-async-await-at-the-top-level)

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there - just missing an `async`.  But for the sake of completeness, here's a couple different strategies for running jQuery animations in sequence

### Chain animate calls

[`.animate()`](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) will automatically place animations in a queue for each element.  This is set to true by default, but you can override by passing in the option `{ queue: false }` to force subsequent animations to fire immediately.

This example will animate `marginLeft` first, then `marginTop` after:

```js
$("#a")
    .animate({marginLeft: "40px"}, 1000)
    .animate({marginTop: "40px"}, 1000)
```

```js
$("#a")
  .animate({marginLeft: "40px"}, 1000)
  .animate({marginTop: "40px"}, 1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a">Hello</div>
```

### Animate + Queue

As just observed, animations will automatically queue, but if you want to add your own methods to the queue, you can call [`.queue()`](https://api.jquery.com/queue/) to add your own code.  Just make sure to call the `next()` param when you are done to start the next action in the queue.

This example will animate `marginLeft` first, then change the text, then animate `marginTop`:

```js
$("#a")
  .animate({marginLeft: "40px"}, 1000)
  .queue(function(next) {
    $(this).text("Hi");
    next();
  })
  .animate({marginTop: "40px"}, 1000)
```

```js
$("#a")
  .animate({marginLeft: "40px"}, 1000)
  .queue(function(next) {
    $(this).text("Hi");
    next();
  })
  .animate({marginTop: "40px"}, 1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a">Hello</div>
```

### Promises + Async / Await

You can convert animations into a promise by calling `.promise()` and then awaiting the promise.

**Note**: Just make sure to mark your function as `async` since [await is only valid in async function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49432579/1366033).

This example will animate `marginLeft` first, then change the text, then animate `marginTop`:

```js
async function main() {
  await $("#a").animate({marginLeft: "40px"}, 1000).promise()
  $("#a").text("Hi");
  await $("#a").animate({marginTop: "40px"}, 1000).promise()
}
main()
```

```js
async function main() {
  await $("#a").animate({marginLeft: "40px"}, 1000).promise()
  $("#a").text("Hi");
  await $("#a").animate({marginTop: "40px"}, 1000).promise()
}
main()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a">Hello</div>
```

### jQuery.When()

You can combine **multiple animations** together by calling [`$.when`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) on multiple deferred elements to step them all at the same time.  That returns a single promise that can be awaited or passed a callback.

This example will complete animations on both elements, then start the next animations:

```js
$.when(
  $("#a").animate({marginLeft: "40px"}, 1000),
  $("#b").animate({marginLeft: "40px"}, 1000),
).then(()=>{
  $("#a").animate({marginTop: "40px"}, 1000);
  $("#b").animate({marginTop: "40px"}, 1000);
})
```

```js
$.when(
  $("#a").animate({marginLeft: "40px"}, 1000),
  $("#b").animate({marginLeft: "40px"}, 1000),
).then(() => {
  $("#a").animate({marginTop: "40px"}, 1000);
  $("#b").animate({marginTop: "40px"}, 1000);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a">Hello</div>
<div id="b">Goodbye</div>
```

### Further Reading

- [JQuery synchronous animation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1594077/1366033)
- [when is asynchronous and when it's not?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8072116/1366033)
- [Single queue for jQuery animate() elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5965371/1366033)
- [JS/jQuery: Wait for function with animations to be finished](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25383514/1366033)